# Differences between bootstrap-flex, bootstrap-grid and bootstrap-reboot

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

In the newest version of Bootstrap (current version at the time of asking the question is `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5`) there are 3 different files and a standard one:

1. bootstrap-flex.css
2. bootstrap-grid.css
3. bootstrap-reboot.css
4. bootstrap.css

Are the first 3 files an extension to `bootstrap.css` (#4)?

I can imagine, that the `bootstrap-flex` use the features of CSS Flexbox, `bootstrap-grid` is probably the old and already existing way, but what about `bootstrap-reboot`?

Which one do I have to include (especially then, if I use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) with Angular 2)?

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss):

**`bootstrap-flex.scss`**

> Bootstrap with Flexbox enabled
>
> Includes all the imports from the standard Bootstrap project, but enables the flexbox variable.

**`bootstrap-grid.scss`**

> Bootstrap Grid only
>
> Includes relevant variables and mixins for the regular (non-flexbox) grid system, as well as the generated predefined classes (e.g., `.col-4-sm`).

**`bootstrap-reboot.scss`**

> Bootstrap Reboot only
>
> Includes only Normalize and our custom Reboot reset.

**`bootstrap.scss`**

> The main Bootstrap library

And the answer is yes, the first 3 files are optional for Bootstrap.

The minimum required is `bootstrap.css`, it already includes `bootstrap-reboot`.

Replace with `bootstrap-grid` if you want the Bootstrap's grid only.

Replace with `bootstrap-flex` if you want to use Bootstrap with Flexbox. It is `bootstrap.css` with Flexbox features.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nhan said: yes, the -reboot, -flex, and -grid files extend the primary bootstrap.css and if you use one of them, then that file is the only you need to include.

As far as the ng-bootstrap portion of your question, I'm using the same and I've only included the bootstrap.min file as I don't plan to use flexbox and I need more than the grid styles.

Hopefully that adds a bit of clarification about what is strictly necessary within the context of your question.